# Finding p-value given observation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, gamma-distribution

Test the following hypothesis

$$H_0:  \lambda=\lambda_0$$
$$H_1:  \lambda \neq \lambda_0$$

null distribution to be ~$gamma(20,20\lambda_0)$ given $\lambda_0=1$ and an observed sample =0.8, find the p-value.

I have tried to find the CDF of the gamma distribution from 0 to 0.8 and multiplying the area by 2 for 2 tailed test, but I am told that is the wrong way to solve it.